# FileSystemRights Issues (C#)

Tags: c#, filesystems, console-application, rights

I'm fairly new to file systems and permissions/rights access (aka Access Control List, ACL). While coding with regards to ACL, I am not able to set properties I want to the files. I'm unsure if my understanding of FileSystemRights members are wrong, or I'm totally doing the wrong thing. (And I'm spending quite some time on this part already)

What I'd like to do is change the rights of a file, so that it can only be soelly readable AND cannot be edited, renamed, deleted and copied elsewhere.

Using the MSDN's example, here's what I have so far:

```
try
{
    //Get current identity
    WindowsIdentity self = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

    // Add the access control entry to the file.
    AddFileSecurity(filename, self.Name, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Deny);
    AddFileSecurity(filename, self.Name, FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Deny);
    AddFileSecurity(filename, self.Name, FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, AccessControlType.Allow);

    // Remove the access control entry from the file.
    RemoveFileSecurity(filename, self.Name, FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, AccessControlType.Deny);
    RemoveFileSecurity(filename, self.Name, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Deny);

    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

My logic is that:

1. Add Deny Modify rights (Denying .Modify will cause the file to become unreadable)
2. Add Deny Write rights
3. Add Allow ReadAndExecute rights
4. Remove Deny entry on ReadAndExecute (As .Modify denies ReadAndExecute)
5. Remove Deny entry on Read (As .Modify denies Read)

Am I doing this part correctly? If not, please advise on what should I do to make the file only readable only and not editable, renamable, deletable and copiable. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As long as the file is readable it will always be copyable!

Comment: Is it then possible (any kind of workaround) to make it readable yet prevent it from being copied elsewhere?

Comment: NO - anything readable is copyable...

Comment: Let's say I'd just set the file attributes to "Read-Only", would the file be then copyable, editable and deletable on other computers?

Comment: it is copyable as long as it is readable... and in turn with the copy everything can be done (edit, delete...)

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what it is doing wrong.  The only thing I see that may be an issue is that you're setting the permissions for yourself, but not the other users, or groups.  Perhaps you should iterate through all the groups (admins, users, etc) and disable all but read&execute.  Although I think SYSTEM always has full control of all files.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the use of this application. It is supposed to reside in a thumbdrive, which will be distributed to different users. That is where the "self.Name" comes in to get their computer domain\user. There are files in the thumbdrive, and they should be only readable, thus I'd have to disallow the functions of copying, editing and deleting - Meaning to say, nothing is to be changed in the thumbdrive, only reading the files.